# How to use in_array / array_push to get similar posts to a custom post?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, array-push

I'm using `array_push` to collect posts that are the same tags to a custom post. I would like to collect unique posts, so I'm using `in_array` to check `id` of a post. It gives me errors like `Object of class App\\Models\\Post could not be converted to int`. So, how can check the `id` of post in array list? Is there another way in laravel without using array?

Thank you.

```
  foreach ($post->tags as $tag) {

        $tag = Tag::where('name', $tag->name)->first();
        
        $posts = $tag->posts;

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            
            if (!in_array($post->id, $similar_posts)) {

                array_push($similar_posts, $post);

            }
        }

    }
```

**Solution:**

I found that it's better to use query because of system performance and optimizing codes. I used below way instead of above way:

```
$tags = $post->tags->pluck('id');

$similar_posts = Post::join('post_tag', 'posts.id', 'post_tag.post_id')->whereIn('post_tag.tag_id', $tags)->whereNotIn('posts.id', [$post->id])->select('posts.*')->distinct('posts.id')->get();
```

It's working well :)

Comment: You push `$post` in array but you check with `$post->id` in `if` condition! you should push `$post->id` Like this ```array_push($similar_posts, $post->id);```

Comment: Please share some output of your `$posts`, `$similar_posts`

Comment: my post contains some data (id, name, type,...) and I would like to have all of it's data.. not just one item like id

Comment: if I use `array_push($similar_posts, $post->id)`, I should again use foreach and query to get that post.. I want to find easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `similar_posts` consists of `Post` items whereas you're looking for integer IDs when doing `in_array` call.

So what you can do is to collect items like this `$similar_posts[$post->id] = $post`. In that case you don't need neither `array_push` nor `in_array`. And the question here why do you need to collect posts at all? The `$tag->posts` contains your posts already.